# how to cancel incoming message sound on Symbian PyS60 

Tags: symbian, nokia, pys60

I am writing a parental control app using PyS60 ( on Nokia E72)
The app is operated via sms's.
Every sms that operates the app is deleted when entering the inbox listener's callback, and by using a blank audio file, I manage to cancel the "new message" sound alert.
However,
this only works when the focus in on Python Script Shell.
Meanning - when I switch to desktop, or any other app that is open, the new message alert sound is playing.
My guess is - I'm losing the race with the messaging module (or process race condition),

Does anyone know how to make this work while running in background?
Or even cancel the process that handles incoming sms's and deal with it myself?
Or lower the priority of the process ??

any other suggestions are also welcome..

thank in advance,
Amitos80